# composer autoload wont work

Tags: php, composer-php, autoload

I have just started a new PHP project and right up front, I am running into issues with the autoloader. I searched for the error and consulted the documentation (http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-4/), but the issue persists.

Hence, I created a minimal example to narrow down the cause of the error - yet, even with this minimal example, it wont work :(

My folder structure is like this:

```
+ src/
| + Xyz.php
+ composer.json
+ test.php
```

Here is my code

composer.json:

```
{
    "name": "sg/ABC",
    "description": "abc",
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "sg\\ABC\\": "src/"
        }
    }
}
```

Xyz.php:

```
<?php namespace sg\ABC;
    class Xyz
    {}
?>
```

test.php:

```
<?php namespace sg\ABC;
    use sg\ABC\Xyz;
    $a = new Xyz();
?>
```

Even though running `composer install` shows no errors, I immediately get this error when running the code:

```
$ php test.php 
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'sg\ABC\Xyz' not found in /dir/x/test.php on line 5

Fatal error: Class 'sg\ABC\Xyz' not found in /dir/x/test.php on line 5
```

also, running `composer dump-autoload` (as suggested here and there in this board) does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still need to include the [composer autoload.php file](https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading) to include the loaded libraries.

Comment: yes, i forgot that in the minimal example. Though, after adding it to the example it worked, but the actual code still didn't. For SOME reason (which I still don't even begin to understand) it works now after copying the code part-by part to a new repository and adding empty classes first, THEN the code. *facepalm*

Answer (score 1):

You need to require the autoloader .. it is usually `require_once "path/to/vendor/autoload.php"`.